# Sort and group results by date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with blog posts. I want to select the most recent posts and using PHP echo a divider between them similar to the example below. I was thinking about storing all results in PHP arrays and then echoing, is there an easier way via MySQL?

```
Thursday, Sept 8th
-----------------------
Post 1 
Post 2

Friday, Sept 9th
-----------------------
post 3
post 4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an idea:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by post_date DESC";
$posts = $con->query($sql);

$previous_date = "";
foreach ($posts as $row){
    //here goes the date
    if($post['post_date'] != $previous_date){
        echo $post['post_date'];
        echo "<br>--------------------<br>";
        $previous_date = $post['post_date'];
    } 
    //here goes the post
    echo "Post:{$post['title']}<br>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm fairly sure there's nothing in MySQL to let you return that result set. If there is, it'll probably be very interesting to see and very hideous :P

Semantically speaking, you don't actually want that coming back from the query; the query should return purely data and then PHP (or whatever) should be responsible for formatting it in the way you want. If the query returns some presentation stuff, you're mixing things up.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a column in the database to store unix timestamps for the times of the posts and then sort by this column (if your asking how to get the most recent posts first ). You could loop through existing rows and convert dates to timestamps using the strftime() function. You should not keep the formatting in the database though, just the data, in case you want to organize it in other ways in other places later on. Good luck.