# Display MySQL results by date

Tags: php, mysql, date, row, sql-order-by

I have this mysql Table:

```
+--------------------+---------+-------+
|      date          | query   | count |
|--------------------+---------+-------|
|2012-11-18 09:52:00 | Michael |   1   |
|2012-11-18 10:47:10 |  Tom    |   2   |
|2012-11-17 15:02:12 |  John   |   1   |
|2012-11-17 22:52:10 |  Erik   |   3   |
|2012-11-16 09:42:01 |  Larry  |   1   |
|2012-11-16 07:41:33 |  Kate   |   1   |
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and so on. I can simply take results and order them by date in one row via this code:

```
$queries = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_tables ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queries)){
    echo "Name ".$row['query']."";
}
```

But how to display elements from table ordered by specific date like this:

```
In 2012-11-18:
Michael
Tom

In 2012-11-17:
John
Erik

In 2012-11-16:
Larry
Kate
```

and so on. Thanks!

Comment: This will give you a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357073/sort-and-group-results-by-date

Comment: most answers are sql related, but you did not point out to have a php related answer. So your question is not clear and is misleading. So downvoting their answers is unfair. Please edit your question and for sure you will get answers to your question in mind

Comment: You just need a [Control break](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break)

Comment: OP has posted expected output which (IMO) makes the question fairly clear. If someone has confusion, the comments option below the question can be used.

Comment: "SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(query) AS queries, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%c-%e') AS day FROM my_tables GROUP BY day ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20"

Comment: Are you expecting to return 20 days or 20 records? HUGE difference.

Comment: do not get confused by all the mysql related stuff here. it is just a pure php question

Comment: Just for fun SQL solution (ommiting the unclear LIMIT stuff:) [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c9b8/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is teh PHP code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT date, query FROM table6 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20");
$group_date = null;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if ($group_date !== substr($row["date"], 0, 10)) {
        $group_date = substr($row["date"], 0, 10);
        echo "<h1>$group_date</h1>\n";
    }
    echo "${row['query']}<br>\n";
}
```

Output:

> ## 2012-11-18
>
> Tom
>
> Michael
>
> ## 2012-11-17
>
> Erik
>
> John
>
> ## 2012-11-16
>
> Larry
>
> Kate

Note that while this code "groups" rows by one column, it can easily be extended to group rows by multiple columns. Left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

+1 good question, THIS QUESTION IS NOT SIMPLY HOW TO ORDER A QUERY!!

I think this can be done using [`GROUP_CONCAT` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). this will combine the matching results when you group them and seperate them by commas. ONce you have the results you can explode or do whatever you want

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Your going to have to convert and group by date, and group_concat the names. then (in php or whathaveyou) explode the names by commas, and echo the date followed by the names for each result.

**edit** Looks like you wanted a PHP way to solve this? oops

Comment: What would happen if a record has a "," in the query field and you explode by that separator?

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_tables WHERE date > "2012-11-16" ORDER BY date LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Your answer would be considerably better if you could explain _why_ it would work. Thinking about why might also help you with the error in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Try the WHERE statement:

```
   select * from my_table where date_column > "2012-11-18 00:00:00" and date_column < "2012-11-18 23:59:59" order by date_column
```

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
 SELECT * FROM my_tables GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DAY(date) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Same question: where did Tom, Eric and Kate go?