# How to split datetime into parts for use in repeating rows

Tags: php, mysql, html

Ok... so I have a table of events in my database table (events).  In the "start" column I have a datetime inserted.  I need to query all the info from the table (title, author, area, start, address, desc) and bring the "start" row out as multiple parts.  The reason?  Because I have the Month and Day and Time all under separate tags in my PHP file.  So I have something that looks like this:

```
<div class="calndr">
<span class="month backcolr">DEC</span>
<span class="day colr bold">27th</span>
</div>
```

This code is a repeating area for each event in my database.
I am using dreamweaver (i know I am on the dark side) but its all I could teach myself.  Any info will be much appreciated!

Comment: This one groups by entire date, modify according to you needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442351/display-mysql-results-by-date/13443671#13443671

Comment: The better way would be to store the date and time as timestamp and format it with PHP. So you could take time zone in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ... DAY(start) as day, MONTH(start) as month, YEAR(start) as year ...
```

Comment: That is exactly what I al looking for!  The only thing is I am getting an error when using it (most likely user error by me).  The code is below>>>

Comment: I figured it out!  I just need to add a , right after I am completed reformating the info coming from the database already!  That you SOOOO much!

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
SELECT title, 
author, 
area, 
MONTHNAME(start) as month,
DAY(start) as day,
TIME(start) as time, 
address, 
desc FROM events
```

If you want to format the month, day or time different you can check this functions in the mysql Documentation. Here is the link for it:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Good luck

Comment: @Dagon you have "..." that results in a MySQL error. You are also using MONTH which will return a number instead of the month name. So I don't see why my answer is less accurate than yours

Comment: Monthname is bad for localization issues

Comment: Same basic idea that I was looking for