# PHP MySQL Query Multiple Categories on a Single Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have an application that categorizes links for a tools page.  On this page I want to have multiple categories and each tool under those categories.  As I am going to have 13 categories (with more as the tool gets used) I don't want to run a query for each category.  I would prefer to run a single query to grab all the data.

Right now I have the page setup so that it displays each category with a drop down to view the tools.  What I need to do is have it so that only the tools for that category show up.  I'm having a problem working out how to go through all of that data from a single query.

Currently I am using a while statement to run through the results as an array.

```
while($tools = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    if($tools['id'] = 1){
        echo $tools['name'];
    }
}
```

This is just a basic mockup of what I currently plan on doing.  I can't help thinking however there is a better way to go about this.  What is the best way to grab a big chunk of data from MySQL and then break it out into categories with PHP?  If I need to run more than a single query that is fine, but I prefer not running a query for each category.

Comment: You can do a left join to get category and tools in each row, then use the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442351/display-mysql-results-by-date

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have performance problems you can use GROUP_CONCAT function like this,

```
SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM tools
GROUP BY id
```

you may read more abut GROUP_CONCAT from mysql official web site [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)