# Simple date grouping using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve a very simple timeline using no 3rd party scripts. I would like to know how to group, based on date, a series of divs, which i'm rendering using a foreach loop in PHP. The array that I'm feeding is sorted based on date but I don't know how to use javascript/jquery to check when the month changes so I can inject a piece of HTML title.

**Something like**

```
10 May 2013
div1; div2; div3
15 May 2013
div4; div5
20 Dec 2013
div7

<?foreach ($notes as $row) :?>
   <p class='dateTag'><?=$row['date'];?></p>
   <p class='title'><?=$row['title'];?></p>
<?endforeach;?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "how to group based on data" ?

Comment: Do you want a PHP solution?

Comment: There are about 300 divs tho.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13442351/87015?

Comment: Can you provide the "foreach loop in PHP" code here?

Comment: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-grouping.html see this link for grouping

Comment: https://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/year.html

Comment: @SalmanA this worked GREAT! Thanks. Should I delete the question, reformat it and vote for your answer (if you post it).

Comment: @Ando: the other answer provides server side solution. You are welcome to vote for that answer. If you're still looking for client side solution you are welcome to keep this question open (just rephrase your requirements).