# How to group rows by month, loop days inside the month and skip to next month using PHP & SQL

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Hi I'm trying to achieve something with my loop from my database and I don't have the solution. I think I'm close to the solution but really need help. I believe I need to make a loop in a loop but not sure how to do that.

How can I group rows by month, loop days inside the months and skip to next month using PHP & SQL?

**The data looks like this:**

```
Creation_date | Project_name
2023-02-24 | Project A
2023-02-22 | Project B
2023-02-22 | Project C
2023-02-21 | Project..
2023-02-13 | Project..

2023-01-28 | Project..
2023-01-20 | Project..

2022-12-31 | Project..
2022-12-02 | Project..

2022-11-09 | Project..

2022-10-26 | Project..
```

**Here is the code**

```
<?php
  $query = '
    SELECT
    Creation_date,
    DATE_FORMAT(Creation_date, "%m") Creation_date_m,
    DATE_FORMAT(Creation_date, "%M") Creation_date_M_full,
    DATE_FORMAT(Creation_date, "%Y") Creation_date_Y_full,
    Project_name
    FROM Projects
    ORDER BY Creation_date DESC
  ';
  $result = $conn->query($query);

  $previousMonth = null;
  $currentMonth = date('m');
?>

<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
  <?php
    $month = $row['Creation_date_m'];
    $monthFull = $row['Creation_date_M_full'];
    $year = $row['Creation_date_Y_full'];

    if (!$previousMonth) {
      $previousMonth = $currentMonth;
    }

    // if there is a change of month, define the class to be set
    if ($month != $previousMonth) {
      $previousMonth = $month;
      $monthName = '<h2>' . $monthFull . ' ' . $year . '</h2>';
    } else {
      $monthName = "";
    }
  ?>

  <div class="month">
    <?= $monthName; ?>
    <div class="day-of-month"><?= $row['Creation_date']; ?></div>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Right now my loop output something like this:**

```
<div class="month">
  <h2>February 2023</h2>
  <div class="day-of-month">2023-02-24</div>
</div>

<div class="month">
  <div class="day-of-month">2023-02-22</div>
</div>

<div class="month">
  <div class="day-of-month">2023-02-22</div>
</div>

<div class="month">
  <h2>January 2023</h2>
  <div class="day-of-month">2023-01-28</div>
</div>

<div class="month">
  <div class="day-of-month">2023-01-20</div>
</div>
```

**But It should output something like this:**

```
<div class="month">
  <h2>February 2023</h2>
  <div class="day-of-month">2023-02-24</div>
  <div class="day-of-month">2023-02-22</div>
  <div class="day-of-month">2023-02-22</div>
</div>

<div class="month">
  <h2>January 2023</h2>
  <div class="day-of-month">2023-01-28</div>
  <div class="day-of-month">2023-01-20</div>
</div>
```

Thank you so much, I hope it's clear :)

Comment: You are outputting the `<div class="month">` every time you go through the loop, regardless of whether the month has changed or not. Move that into the section where you set the header.

Comment: should be closed as a dupe for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357073/sort-and-group-results-by-date

Comment: @YourCommonSense It's similar, but not an exact duplicate. This needs a head and tail around each month, not just a standalone separator between months. If the OP is already struggling, I wouldn't assume the additional step would be obvious/trivial for them.

Comment: @MatBailie then write additional answer there, so it will be of help for many people coming from Google. Having a single solid answer is much better than an assortment of quick and dirty sketches with untested code and possible typos. this is what duplicated answers for

Comment: @YourCommonSense I've never written php, so I've added to the litany of bad answers ;) feel free to edit it, or as you say yourself, write your own answer.q

Answer (score 0):

You need to only output the month div if it changes. Something like this (untested) code:

```
<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
  <?php
    $month = $row['Creation_date_m'];
    $monthFull = $row['Creation_date_M_full'];
    $year = $row['Creation_date_Y_full'];

    // if there is a change of month, define the class to be set
    if ($month != $previousMonth) {
      $monthName = '<div class="month"><h2>' . $monthFull . ' ' . $year . '</h2>';
      $monthEnd = '</div>';
    } else {
      $monthName = "";
      $monthEnd = "";
    }
    echo $monthName; 
    ?>
    <div class="day-of-month"><?= $row['Creation_date']; ?></div>
    <?php
    $previousMonth = $month; // set it here so it changes every time.
    echo $monthEnd;
endwhile; ?>
```

If the month changes, `$monthName` contains the header and `$monthEnd` contains the closer, otherwise they're both empty.

You don't need to check if `$previousMonth` is null, because it'll still be different to the month you get back from the database. You do need to change it every time you output a row, not just every time you output a header.

I'm not sure where `$rowCountTable` came from, so I changed it to `$row` inside the loop. Maybe a typo on here.

Comment: Hi thank you so much, I will test the code. For the $rowCountTable, it's my mistake, it should be $row, thank you!

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, do you think we should use nested loop ? like loop the div.month and inside I put another loop for div.day-of-month?

Comment: @TonyChheng Never use the phrase "it doesn't work", it has no useful information. Instead, update your question (or ask a new question) and include the exact code you tried and the Exact output you generated.

Comment: @droopsnot Don't echo month end Every loop. Echo it only if there's a month change, except for the first loop, and an extra time after the loop finishes.

Comment: Hi @MatBailie thank you for your answer, I will update it and also sorry for the it doeant work, I'll be better next time :)

Comment: @MatBailie you are correct, but as it will be empty if the month hasn't changed, it just saves another if-else clause. Yes, it'll need a closing div after the loop, I forgot that bit.

Comment: @TonyChheng in what way is it not working? I didn't test the code as I don't have your database table, so there may be typos. But the principle should be OK. I don't think there's a need to have a nested loop. I just fixed a typo, made a mess of quotes, the line should read `$monthEnd = "</div>";` of course.

Comment: this is why, exactly, there are best practices that programmers are expected to follow. Such as not to mix the database code with HTML output code. And format HTML as HTML, not as PHP strings, creating a "mess of quotes"

Comment: using bad practices in your own code makes only your own code bad. using bad practices in the public answer, makes WAY much more code bad. And makes much pore people laugh at PHP

Comment: @YourCommonSense which bad practices specifically am I using here? I'm learning, not arguing.

Comment: "Such as not to mix the database code with HTML output code. And format HTML as HTML, not as PHP strings, creating a "mess of quotes"

Comment: you can get a 2-dim array from mysql, indexed by year-month, then output it in HTML using nested loops

Comment: You still do this; notice new month, write opening month div, write day div, write month closing div, move on to new row. So, the first day is within a month div, but the remaining days (for the same month) are outside of the month div.

Comment: @MatBailie I do, but if the month hasn't changed, the two variables will be empty. Your code is neater, though.

Comment: Yours; `<MONTH><day></day></MONTH><day></day><day></day><MONTH><day></day></MONTH><day></day><day></day>`

Comment: Mine: `<MONTH><day></day><day></day><day></day></MONTH><MONTH><day></day><day></day><day></day></MONTH>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP programmer, but the basic structure should be:

- read next row from db
- if row is for a different month, write a `<\div>` AND a `<div>`
- write the div for the current db row
- loop back to read all db rows
- write a final closing div for the last month

The only caution to the above is to make sure you done write a closing div before the first opening div.

The below should do that, if I understand the PHP syntax correctly.

```
<?php
  $query = '
    SELECT
    Creation_date,
    DATE_FORMAT(Creation_date, "%m") Creation_date_m,
    DATE_FORMAT(Creation_date, "%M") Creation_date_M_full,
    DATE_FORMAT(Creation_date, "%Y") Creation_date_Y_full,
    Project_name
    FROM Projects
    ORDER BY Creation_date DESC
  ';
  $result = $conn->query($query);

  $previousMonth = "";
  $closeMonth = "";
?>
<?php
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):
?>
  <?php
    $month = $row['Creation_date_m'];
    $monthFull = $row['Creation_date_M_full'];
    $year = $row['Creation_date_Y_full'];

    // if the month has changed
    // - record the month in previousMonth
    // - close the preceding month, if there was one
    // - open the new month
    if ($month != $previousMonth) {
      $previousMonth = $month;
      echo $closeMonth;
      echo '<div class="month">' ;
      echo '<h2>' . $monthFull . ' ' . $year . '</h2>';
      $closeMonth = '<\div>';
    }
  ?>
    <div class="day-of-month"><?= $row['Creation_date']; ?></div>
<?php
  endwhile;
  echo $closeMonth
?>
```